# How to write on the right of the page when i when I divided the page into 2 parts with command \documentclass[twocolumn]

Tags: two-column

[image]

I wrote like this. And i didn't know how to wire on the right of the page as image below.

Comment: Try `\newpage`. In two column it means the next column. If you don't want anything at all in the left column try `\leavevmode\newpage`.

Comment: You may want `parallel` package, if you are doing glosses, translations, or notes. `twocolumn` mode is for continuous text, like a journal article.

Comment: `paracol` is another, and more recent, package that can do parallel text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your question. In a `twocolumn` document output starts in the left column and when that is full it moves to the right column and when that is full it moves to the left column on the next page.

If you want the left column to be empty try `\mbox{}\newpage`, but you can't start on a right column and then move back to the previous left column.